# Can't compile App with watch kit extension in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, watchkit

It was compiling & working great until I updated the developer's tools (El capitan + Xcode 7)

I'm getting this compiler error :

```
SDK is platform 'com.apple.platform.iphoneos' and it needs to match platform 'com.apple.platform.watchos'
```

I tried to add `watchOS` and `watchsimulator` to the `supported platform` and added `armv7k` to the `supported architecture` of the `framework`, but nothing did the trick.